# Which package do I have to import to use FieldValueType?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Which package do I have to import to use FieldValueType on flutter ?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to import

```
cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+1
```

For more information please visit

https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore#-installing-tab-

Comment: Add following to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+1